# How to I change the extension of a .txt file?

Tags: rename

I have a .txt file but i need a .bat or .sh file, but i am new and do not know what to do. I have tried a couple of things, but none have worked so far. Any help?

Comment: What did you try, and how exactly did it fail? in general, file extensions don't have any special meaning in Linux systems - so changing them is no different than renaming the file

Comment: there is a `rename` command, though `mv` (move) is usually easier for single file renames  (`rename` is better for the more complex renames, esp. if you're new to regex's)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

To rename a file, you can just use the mv command.
`mv filename.txt filename.sh`

I hope this helps.